# Deleting the row of a Table in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I added a table, but I have some particular row that I want to delete it. 
How can I do that?

Comment: could you please be more specific on your question?

Comment: you have to at least specify what you mean with "table" ... are you talking about data sets? Or about string grids? Or about TTableWithoutRowDeletion?

Comment: To rephrase the 'Smasher's question: What component did you drop on the form / data module? (I mean it's "type": TTable, TStringGrid...)?

Answer (score 3):

TDataSet.Delete is the obvious answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a TTable, you can use the FindKey method to position the cursor on the correct row and then just call the Delete method of TTable.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no index in your table (to use the FindKey as Jim mentioned), you can search manually for the record you want to delete, for ex:

```
if TTable.FieldsByName('FieldName').AsString='CertainValue'
  TTable.Delete;
```